# Chunk.draw() not working in python IDLE

Tags: python, nltk

I am unable to draw chunked data in Python IDLE, i am successfully printing it in Python cmd, I am using python 2.7 and i am following tutorials on youtube, I found [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imPpT2Qo2sk), but i am unable to get desired result by using draw() function.
Here is my code, kindly suggest me if i am doing any thing wrong,

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import state_union
from nltk import PunktSentenceTokenizer
'''
POS tag list:

CC  Coordinating conjunction
CD  Cardinal number
DT  Determiner
EX  Existential there
FW  Foreign word
IN  Preposition or subordinating conjunction
JJ  Adjective
JJR Adjective, comparative
JJS Adjective, superlative
LS  List item marker
MD  Modal
NN  Noun, singular or mass
NNS Noun, plural
NNP Proper noun, singular
NNPS    Proper noun, plural
PDT Predeterminer
POS Possessive ending
PRP Personal pronoun
PRP$    Possessive pronoun
RB  Adverb
RBR Adverb, comparative
RBS Adverb, superlative
RP  Particle
SYM Symbol
TO  to
UH  Interjection
VB  Verb, base form
VBD Verb, past tense
VBG Verb, gerund or present participle
VBN Verb, past participle
VBP Verb, non-3rd person singular present
VBZ Verb, 3rd person singular present
WDT Wh-determiner
WP  Wh-pronoun
WP$ Possessive wh-pronoun
WRB Wh-adverb
'''
train_text = state_union.raw("2005-GWBush.txt")
sample_text = state_union.raw("2006-GWBush.txt")

custom_sent_tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(train_text) #A

tokenized = custom_sent_tokenizer.tokenize(sample_text)   #B

def process_content():
try:
    for i in tokenized:
        words = nltk.word_tokenize(i)
        tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)
        chunkGram = r"""Chunk: {<RB.?>*<VB.?>*<NNP>+<NN>} """
        chunkParser = nltk.RegexpParser(chunkGram)
        chunked = chunkParser.parse(tagged)

        chunked.draw()

except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

process_content()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python version 2.7 do not provide such facility, i installed Python 3.6 and now chunk.draw() is working fine.